# How to add/remove a background color using jQuery and html5 data attributes

Tags: jquery

I am trying to add an unique background color to the label of check boxes when they are clicked (the check boxes themselves are hidden). I can get it to add the background color but it will not remove it once it is applied. What I have (https://jsfiddle.net/9oq88dro/):

**CSS**

```
label {user-select:none}
input {position: absolute; left: -9999px;}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <input id="1" type="checkbox" value="test 1"><label for="1" data-color="red">test 1</label>
  <input id="2" type="checkbox" value="test 2"><label for="2" data-color="blue">test 2</label>
  <input id="3" type="checkbox" value="test 3"><label for="3" data-color="green">test 3</label>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.container label').on('click', function() {
  if ($(this).css('background-color', '')) {
    $(this).css('background-color', $(this).data("color"));
  } else {
    $(this).css('background-color', '');
  }
});
```

Comment: `css(key, value)` is the setter.  Did you mean to use `css(key)` to get the value of 'background-color' ?

Comment: At first I was just trying to check if the input has been checked or not. I did not know how to make a selector for the input based off the label that was clicked, so I checked the label for no background instead. As there shouldn't be one if the box has not been checked.

Comment: Isn't simpler to wrap inputs and text into `<label>` without using ID and FOR?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some browsers will return `background-color` in `rgb()` and `rgba()`, not necessarily the color name you've given it. If you just want to toggle the color on and off, you could toggle a class to determine the state.

```js
$('.container label').on('click', function() {
  var color = $(this).data('color');
  if (!$(this).hasClass('color')) {
    $(this).css('background-color', color);
    $(this).addClass('color');
  } else {
    $(this).css('background-color', 'transparent');
    $(this).removeClass('color');
  }
});
```

```css
label {
  user-select: none
}

input {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <input id="1" type="checkbox" value="test 1">
  <label for="1" data-color="red">test 1</label>
  <input id="2" type="checkbox" value="test 2">
  <label for="2" data-color="blue">test 2</label>
  <input id="3" type="checkbox" value="test 3">
  <label for="3" data-color="green">test 3</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Interesting, this is exactly what I was trying to achieve. Why does adding the class toggle make it work? Does it force an update in the browser?

Comment: Actually the default initial value for `background-color` should be `"transparent"` and Chrome is the only to return `"rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)"`

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan when I `console.log`ged `$(this).css('background-color')` the console in chrome said `rgba(0,0,0,0)` https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zzoPMP

Comment: OK let me repeat: Firefox, IE, Edge give the correctly expected `"transparent"` while Chrome is the only one to miss it - giving `"rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)"`

Comment: @MichaelCoker no I'm not the downvoter, but you could correctly state what's going on.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I changed the wording. I didn't mean all browsers would return that, just that browsers don't return it consistently. That's what I meant by "not necessarily the color name you've given it." Sorry if that was unclear.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan ah thanks. Looks like they reverted the downvote.

Comment: @MichaelCoker np. BTW: https://drafts.csswg.org/css-backgrounds-3/#background-color << see about the default (initial) value - clearly not respected by Chrome (although technically rgba(0,0,0,0) *is* transparent :D)

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan nice, thanks! Yeah chrome is right... just a weird way to do it, but I found this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-color?v=control apparently `The transparent keyword maps to rgba(0,0,0,0).` so I guess Chrome is just taking that extra step and applying `rgba(0,0,0,0)` directly so it doesn't have to map/convert anything.

Comment: @MichaelCoker Chrome clearly does it wrong. If the Specification states that the *Initial* value should be `"transparent"`... I'm not sure why than the Chrome team decided to do it that way... going with `"rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)"`. Probably a mistake that - at this stage - is better left untouched!?..

Answer (score 0):

Looks like css was returning `rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)`.  You could use just the dom properties if you wanted though.

```js
$('.container label').on('click', function() {
  if (!this.style.backgroundColor) {
    this.style.backgroundColor = $(this).data("color");
  } else {
    this.style.backgroundColor = '';
  }
});
```

```css
label {user-select:none}
input {position: absolute; left: -9999px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <input id="1" type="checkbox" value="test 1"><label for="1" data-color="red">test 1</label>
  <input id="2" type="checkbox" value="test 2"><label for="2" data-color="blue">test 2</label>
  <input id="3" type="checkbox" value="test 3"><label for="3" data-color="green">test 3</label>
</div>
```

Comment: (Not sure about Safari) but Chrome is the only one to give String `"rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)"` - all other browsers respectfully give back the expected initial `"transparent"`

Comment: I had a small question. How would you add to the jquery, if I wanted the color of test 1 to dissapear once I clicked on test 2 and henceforth. This means only one background color shows at a time, like an active link.?